# addition assignment overloading (passing by pointer)

Tags: c++

Based on this link addition assignment overloaded using stack and passing by value:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH3R_8.0.0/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr318.htm%23cplr318?lang=en

```
complx complx::operator+ (const complx& c) const
{
      complx result;
      result.real = (this->real + c.real);
      result.imag = (this->imag + c.imag);
      return result;
}
```

bu I want to use something like this:

```
 complx& complx::operator+ (const complx& c) const
    {
          complx result = new complx;
          result->real = (this->real + c.real);
          result->imag = (this->imag + c.imag);
          return *result;
    }
```

Is this correct? Where should I release the heap? Is there any better way?

Comment: Why do you want to return a reference to something you just created on the heap? What about the first signature worries you?

Comment: The first example *is* the "better way". Can you explain what problem you have with the first way?

Comment: My be I am wrong, but I always try to avoid passing by value (copying the value unnecessarily and stack has a limited size).

Comment: Your attempted code just makes it hard for the compiler to optimize. Probably you will find that the first one doesn't even use any stack at all, and it just constructs `result` directly in the calling function.

Comment: Not to mention that even if the first example *isn't* getting optimised to in-place construction, it's still going to be faster and not have the memory management headaches of allocating from heap and very likely leaking the result.

Answer (score 3):

Copying by value doesn't have the old stigma associated with it anymore, since C++11. Compilers are allowed to elide copies. Failing that, they are required to move variables in copy elidable situations. One very common such situation is when you are returning an automatic function variable. In your first example, `result` while be moved at the very least. It will most likely be NRVOed. So, implement a move constructor for `complx`, if needed and use the first signature.

Comment: Good advice in general, but in this case `complx` contains 2 `double`s, so a move constructor is not going to do any good.

Comment: @Praetorian <facepalm>. You are right, of course :)

Comment: C++98 also have copy elision and NRVO so pass-by-value was also preferable there

Comment: @MattMcNabb but if the compiler chose not to elide the copy, the fallback was the copy constructor. While this is fine for simple situations, a function with multiple returns might not get NRVOed even when copy elision was theoretically possible. With C++11, there's one less thing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper way to release allocated memory which you take into method unless manually reallocation by yourself. You might use [SmartPointers](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31529) for allocation . It will release memory when you done with it. Another way to release it is Garbage Collection which not exists in C++.